# Make array consecutive

Tags: javascript

i got stucked in a chalenge in codeFights.my code pass the simple test and fail in just 2 from five of hidden tests her is the chalenge instruction:

Ratiorg got statues of different sizes as a present from CodeMaster for his birthday, each statue having an non-negative integer size. Since he likes to make things perfect, he wants to arrange them from smallest to largest so that each statue will be bigger than the previous one exactly by 1. He may need some additional statues to be able to accomplish that. Help him figure out the minimum number of additional statues needed.

```
Example

For statues = [6, 2, 3, 8], the output should be
makeArrayConsecutive2(statues) = 3.

Ratiorg needs statues of sizes 4, 5 and 7.

Input/Output

[time limit] 4000ms (js)
[input] array.integer statues

An array of distinct non-negative integers.

Constraints:
1 ≤ statues.length ≤ 10,
0 ≤ statues[i] ≤ 20.

[output] integer
```

The minimal number of statues that need to be added to existing statues such that it contains every integer size from an interval [L, R] (for some L, R) and no other sizes.

and here is my code :

```
function makeArrayConsecutive2(statues) {
 //range the table from min to max
 var rang=statues.sort();
 var some=0;
 //if the table is one element
 if(rang.length-1==0){
  return 0;

 }else{
  //if the table contain more then one element
  for(i=0;i<=rang.length-2;i++){
   //add the deference of two consecutive position -1 
   //to find the number of missing numbers
   some+=(rang[i+1]-rang[i]-1);
 }
  return some;
 }
}
```

Comment: Is the question about finding missing values?

Comment: If only count is required, then a faster algo for larger arrays would be `(largest-smallest)+1-arr.length`, since it requires one O(n) traversal for finding smallest and largest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Everything is correct, except the sorting part.

You have used sort function to sort the array in increasing order

```
var rang = statues.sort();
```

But if sort function is not provided a compare function, it converts its elements in strings and then sort it in unicode order.

For eg: [2,1,11] will be sorted as [1,11,2] which will give undesired output.

Correct way is

```
var rang = statues.sort(function (a, b){
    return (a - b) 
});
```

Comment: Nicely spotted but please explain a bit. You are answering for readers and not for OP. That will help more. :-)

Answer (score 4):

SO THE LOGIC TO SOLVE THIS QUESTION IS:

1. Find the Smallest and Largest Element in Array.
2. Get the **count** of can say, difference of Largest and Smallest value of array in order to calculate, how many elements must be there to make it as a continuous array
   . Like from 5 to 9, count of total elements must be 5 ( i.e.5,6,7,8,9) and also **add 1 to the result** to make count **inclusive**.
3. Find the Length of the Array
4. Subtract the **count** i.e. "difference of largest and smallest value " with the length of array

PYTHON CODE (For explanation):

```python3
def makeArrayConsecutive2(statues):
    max_height = max(statues)
    min_height = min(statues)
    array_length  = len(statues)

    count_of_element = max_height - min_height + 1
    # '1 ' is added to make it inclusive
  
    return count_of_element-array_length
```

and Python one liner :

```python3
def makeArrayConsecutive2(statues):
    return max(statues)-min(statues)-len(statues)+1
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function makeArrayConsecutive2(statues) {
  const nums = [];

  for (let i = Math.min(...statues); i <= Math.max(...statues); i++) {
    if (!statues.includes(i)) {
      nums.push(i);
    }
  }

  return nums.length;
}

console.log(makeArrayConsecutive2([6, 2, 3, 8]))
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Deepak's Solution. The question is ready not about sorting but helping to figure out the minimum number of additional statues needed. You only need to get the max and min values.

```
int makeArrayConsecutive2(int[] statues) 
{
    int min=Integer.MAX_VALUE,max=-1;
    for(int i=0;i<statues.length;i++)
    {
        if(statues[i] < min){ min = statues[i]; }
        if(statues[i] > max){ max = statues[i]; }
    }
     return (max-min)+1 - statues.length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution in typescript. Create a new array from the min and max from the status array using a for loop. Subtract new array length with status array length.

```
function makeArrayConsecutive2(statues: number[]): number {

    let min = Math.min(...statues);
    let max = Math.max(...statues);
    let arr = [];

    for (let i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        arr.push(i);
    }

    return arr.length - statues.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorting (nlogn)is not required. Below is the solution in Java.

```
int makeArrayConsecutive2(int[] statues) {
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < statues.length; i++) {
            max = Math.max(max, statues[i]);
            min = Math.min(min, statues[i]);
        }
        return (max - min) + 1 - statues.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Code works

```
var statues = [2, 3, 6, 8];  
var newStatues = [];
```

Function declaration

```
function makeArrayConsecutive2(statues) {
    statues.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b });
    for(var i = statues[0]; i <= statues[statues.length-1]; i++) {
        newStatues.push(i);
    }
    return console.log(newStatues.length - statues.length);
}
```

Function Calling

```
makeArrayConsecutive2(statues);
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution goes here in just O(1) complexity:

```
let n = statues.length;
let max = Math.max.apply(null, statues);
let min = Math.min.apply(null, statues);
return max - min - n + 1;
```

Comment: This may answer the question. However, code only answers are not as useful as answers that document the code or have an detailed explanation on why this code is the solution to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
function makeArrayConsecutive2(statues) {
    var rang = statues.sort(function (a, b){
        return (a - b) 
    });
    var some=0;
 
    if(rang.length-1==0){
        return 0;
    }else{
    for(i=0;i<=rang.length-2;i++){
        some+=(rang[i+1]-rang[i]-1);
    }
    return some;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function makeArrayConsecutive2(statues) {
  const n = statues.length;
  const min = Math.min(...statues);
  const max = Math.max(...statues);
  return max - min - n + 1;
}
```

If we subtract the minimum from the maximum element, then we get the number of elements that should be in the final array. Now subtract the already existing number of elements from this amount and add 1, then we get the result we need - the number of missing elements

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun in C#

```
static int makeArrayConsecutive2(int[] statues)
        {
            List<int> ConsecutiveNums = new List<int>();
            for(int i = statues.Min(); i != statues.Max() + 1; i++)
                ConsecutiveNums.Add(i);           
            return ConsecutiveNums.Count - statues.Length;         
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function makeArrayConsecutive2(statues) {
    return Math.max(...statues) - Math.min(...statues) + 1 -(statues.length) 
}
```

I don't think we need a Looping there, that's my solution

Answer (score 0):

you can try using for loop and ternary operation by the following code

```
def makeArrayConsecutive2(statues):
count=0
for i in range (min(statues),max(statues)):
    count=count+1 if i not in statues else count
return count
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function makeArrayConsecutive2(statues) {
    s = statues.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
    n = statues.length;
    val = 0;

    for (let i=0;i<n-1;i++) {
        val += (Math.abs(s[i]-s[i+1]))-1;
    }

    return val;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
sort(statues.begin(), statues.end());
int count = 0;

for(int i = 1;i<statues.size(); i++){
    int diff = statues[i]-statues[i-1];
    if(diff>1){
        count+=diff-1; 
    }
}

return count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution in PHP

```
function solution($statues) {
    return max($statues) - min($statues) - count($statues) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP solution for question.

```
function solution($statues) {

sort($statues); 
$missing = 0;
$lowest = min($statues);
$highest = max($statues);

$numbers = range($lowest, $highest);

foreach($numbers as $number){
    if(!in_array($number, $statues)){
       $missing++; 
    }
}

return $missing;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

here is code in python

```
def solution(statues):
   statues.sort()
   c = 0
   for i in range(len(statues)-1):
        if statues[i+1]-statues[i] > 1:
            c += statues[i+1]-statues[i] -1
   return (c)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

```
def solution(statues):
    sorted_statues = sorted(statues)
    s = 0
    for i in range(len(sorted_statues)-1):
        diff = sorted_statues[i + 1] - sorted_statues[i]
        if diff > 1:
            s+=diff-1
    return s
```

Comment: Is that indentation-aware python? In that case please note that the question is not tagged python but is tagged java-script. Also, if you do insist on providing a solution in a different language, please learn enough about formatting to get the indentation right. https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Also, please [edit] to make more obvious what the technically relevant difference is between your python code and the similar looking python code in the existing answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70727991/7733418 Reiterating already given solutions, without providing a different explanation of explaining a different approach of logical explanation is rarely seen as a valuable answer.